# Magento 2 add prefix in Invoice number

Tags: magento2, create-invoice

I want to add a prefix like "abc-" in invoice number. (not in order number)

For this, I found,

Magento module: **module-sales-sequence**

File: **/vendor/magento/module-sales-sequence/Model/Sequence.php**

Function: **getCurrentValue**

How to use it in my custom module?

And I want to add prefix in only invoice number.

Comment: Is there anyone who knows the solution?